# Change the color of header in Rmarkdown Prettydoc templates

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

Using the package `prettydoc` in R Markdown, there is a template, the code is below

```
---
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: Harry Potter
date: July 31, 2016
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
---
```

The output look likes this

[image]

Was wondering where I would be able to change the colors that transcend, so maybe it could go from a red to orange or anything I declare. Where is the .css for this header located? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to override the Bootswatch Cayman theme CSS.
To get the default values of the `linear-gradient()` CSS function, responsible for "a [progressive transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) between two or more colors along a straight line" you may "right-click an element on a web page and select *[Inspect Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector)*":

[image]

> Was wondering where I would be able to change the colors that transcend, so maybe it could go from a red to orange...

So, applying CSS Linear Gradients [Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp):
`background-image: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);`

````
---
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: Harry Potter
date: July 31, 2016
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
---

```{css my-header-colors, echo = FALSE}
.page-header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, red, orange);
}
```
````

we get the output:
[image]

> Where is the .css for this header located?

Github: https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc/blob/master/inst/resources/css/cayman.css
Windows (PC): ..\R\win-library\4.0\prettydoc\resources\css\cayman.css

Does this help in any way?

Comment: Yes, Thank you.`linear-gradient()` is a great trick!